# How add a specific variable into Azure Devops Libraries?

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my pipeline (bash, ubuntu-latest) i want to add into already created library a variable (last git commit hash) is it possible ??

Documentation not telling too much about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this API to update the variable group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Use this predefined variable "Build.SourceVersion" to get the latest commit ID: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

[image]

Bash script:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjName}t/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{variablegroupsID}?api-version=7.0' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {Base64PAT}=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "variables": {
        "test": {
            "value": "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
        }
    },
    "id": 5,
    "type": "Vsts",
    "name": "1013",
    "description": "",
    "createdBy": {
        "displayName": "{displayName}",
        "id": "{id}",
        "uniqueName": "{uniqueName}"
    },
    "createdOn": "2022-10-13T07:41:40.3066667Z",
    "modifiedBy": {
        "displayName": "{displayName}",
        "id": "{id}",
        "uniqueName": "{uniqueName}"
    },
    "modifiedOn": "2022-10-13T07:41:40.3066667Z",
    "isShared": false,
    "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
        {
            "projectReference": {
                "id": "{Proj id}",
                "name": "{Proj Name}"
            },
            "name": "1013",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
}'
```

Variable group sample:

[image]

Running the script via Azure Pipeline (bash, ubuntu-latest)

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

**Update1**

[image]

Comment: Hi , thank you for help. Its almost works  PUT from postman its works but in ADO its not working ,nothing is updated. I used a manual for auth from this -  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Linux)

Comment: Hi @Cezu , I have updated my answer. Since it works well in Postman, you could check the corresponding cURL.

Comment: HI im converting it using `MY_PAT=mypatmypatmypat 
        B64_PAT=$(printf "%s"":$MY_PAT" | base64)` and later im using in curl `--header 'Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}' ` still not working :( maybe i should add a username in url